# How to move the sequence of a 2d array in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to implement a function that is able to translate(rotate) the sequence of a 2d array to the desired destination index. A, B, and C represents the length of the sequence.  Source is the beginning of the sequence to be rotated.  Source in the example below would be A.  Dst is the index of the beginning of the target moving.
Input/Output example:
Before:

```
double A[][2] = { {0,0}, {1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}, {4,4}, {5,5}, {6,6}, {7,7} };
                          ^dst                          A      B      C
```

call translate(A, 8, 5, 3, 1);
After:

```
{ {0,0}, {5,5}, {6,6}, {7,7}, {1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}, {4,4} };
           A      B      C
```

A,B,and C , and dst are simply a visualization of what the function should do.

I want to be able to to rotate the sequence(indexes, A, B, and C) to the desired destination index(dst).   Below is the attempt I have tried:

```
/*
A-list of locations; 2d array
cities- number of cities
src-index of the beginning of the sequence to be moved
len- length of sequence to translate
dst-index of the beginning of the target of moving
*/

void translate(double A[][2], int cities, int source, int length, int 
 destination){
            vector<vector<int>> variable;
            //to move sequence
            for(int i = (source + length) % cities; i < destination; i++){
                vector<int> variable2;
                variable2.push_back(A[i][0]);
                variable2.push_back(A[i][1]);
                variable.push_back(variable2);
            }
             
            else{
                return;
             }
             
             //get vector into array
             for(int i = 0; i < citiesl i++){
                 A[i][0] = variable[i][0];
                 A[i][1] = variable[i][1];
              }
        }
```

The errors I have received are

> debug assertion failed: vector subscript out of range

The function returns nothing after it compiles. Is there a way to do this without vectors?

Comment: You asked this question before, and were told what to fix: How do you get A, B, C, and dst? How are they related to the function parameters cities, source, length, and destination. You need to make this clear in the question.

Comment: @cigen I am simply providing a visualization of what the function is supposed to do by providing an illustration.

Comment: "*They are not related to parameters of function except destination.*" That's not true; they need to be calculated based on `src` and `len` as well. I've edited the question to make it a little clearer

Comment: @jb20 Does my post answer your question or do you actually want to use a C-style array? A version like yours can be fixed with something like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fAHfpSnrfbySvc6h) but this is not very elegant.

Comment: @2b-t Your answer does make sense to me.  One thing I am confused about is what can I do with the length variable in my parameter.  I have to use it because it determines the length of the sequence I want to move or rotate.

Comment: @jb20 I do not completely understand. Can you add some more examples on what happens for different input parameters of this length? Do you just want to move it to a certain position and not rotate the entire vector? So a function call should only move the next `length` elements from `source` to `destination`?

Comment: @jb20 I see, I misunderstood that you actually were looking for. I will adjust it...

Comment: @jb20 Changed my answer (see the section `Edit`).

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use the **standard library containers** there is a standard library function that helps you achieve this: **[`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)**

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> A = { {0,0}, {1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}, {4,4}, {5,5}, {6,6}, {7,7} };

// Rotate left by n
std::rotate(A.begin(), A.begin()+n, A.end());

// Rotate right by n
std::rotate(A.rbegin(), A.rbegin()+n, A.rend());
```

In your case this can be written excluding the first element as

```
template <template <typename T, typename Alloc> class Cont, typename T, typename Alloc>
void custom_rotate(Cont<T, Alloc>& vec, std::size_t const source_index, std::size_t const destination_index) {
  // Rotate right excluding first element
  if (source_index < destination_index) {
    std::size_t const digits {destination_index - source_index};
    std::rotate(vec.rbegin() + 1, vec.rbegin() + 1 + digits, vec.rend());
  // Rotate left excluding first element
  } else if (source_index > destination_index) {
    std::size_t const digits {source_index - destination_index};
    std::rotate(vec.begin() + 1, vec.begin() + 1 + digits, vec.end());
  }
  return;
}
```

Try it [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZhRPCjHtZj73CJoP).

---

**Edit**

After a conversation with the original poster we realised that what he wanted was no rotation but instead a translation. This can also be done by **inserting and erasing elements of the vector** as follows

```
template <template <typename T, typename Alloc> class Cont, typename T, typename Alloc>
void translate(Cont<T, Alloc>& vec, std::size_t const source_index, std::size_t const destination_index, std::size_t const number_of_elements) {
  // Insert elements
  vec.insert(vec.begin()+destination_index, vec.begin()+source_index, vec.begin()+source_index+number_of_elements);
  // Delete elements
  vec.erase(vec.begin()+source_index+number_of_elements, vec.begin()+source_index+2*number_of_elements);
  return;
}
```

[Try it here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/snYLEEM9TbhVveOX)

Comment: This version works for C++11 onwards. Without brace-initialisation this works also in C++03.

Comment: FWIW, you can be more concise and write `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> A = { {0,0},{1,1},{2,2}...` instead of each time using `make_pair()`

Comment: @kebs Ah, yeah, forgot to change that. Used a tuple before instead of a pair. Changing it!